# How can I find the position of an HTML element relative to the entire desktop screen using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

How do i find the X,Y coordinates of a particular html element ( eg. div, table, lable, etc...) relative to the desktop screen (i.e. outside the browser window) using JavaScript?

I can find the height and width of the element by using `offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth`, but can't find anything that can give me exact X,Y coordinate of the element relative to the user’s entire desktop screen.

Comment: I think you need to do some trick by getting the user's `resolution` and then using `window` `width` and `height` you can conclude the correct position of the element, it is just a thought you can try it out.

Comment: When you say the “desktop screen”, do you mean the browser window, or something outside the browser window? I don’t think JavaScript has access to the position of the browser window itself relative to the operating system’s screen.

Comment: @Paul by desktop screen i actually mean region outside the browser. i.e the resolution the user has set to his desktop

Comment: right, gotcha. Good question: AFAIK it isn’t possible, but maybe someone else will have an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to follow the tree up, through the parents, and keep adding the offsets, like described here:

http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/90547-how-get-absolute-position-element

```
function getY( oElement )
{
    var iReturnValue = 0;
    while( oElement != null ) {
        iReturnValue += oElement.offsetTop;
        oElement = oElement.offsetParent;
    }
    return iReturnValue;
}
```

Comment: That is relative to the browser window; not the desktop screen.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is not possible even it is quite simple.

1. Find the position of browser relative to screen
2. Find the element position relative to view port.
3. Add the coordinates and you will have the output you want

Follow the piece of code I written:

```
var element = document.getElementById("ID of the element");// you can use any method to find the element ..
var position = getPosition(element);
function getPositions(obj)
{
        var p = [];
        var position =  obj.getBoundingClientRect();
        p[0] = window.screenX + position.left;
        p[1] = window.screenY + position.top;
        p[2] = position.width;
        p[3] = position.height;
        return p;

}
```

Comment: This misses the browsers toolbar or other offsets between browser borders and the document. There are other solutions using `window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight` but this still lacks the fact that a browser might have offsets at the bottom of the window. Actually there is no perfect solution.